# Celda en blanco de un DataGridView luego de ser cargada por una variable con datos

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

Recupero información de una base de datos en `SQL` y una vez la tabla la tengo volcada en un `DataGridView` a esta le agrego columnas con la intención de ingresar información relevante a el dato que tiene cargado en cada fila. el problema se origina cuando los datos que se cargan en los `strings` obtenidos desde la función `CalcularStocks` no se plasman en las celdas y directamente aparecen las columnas agregadas pero vacías. Ya revise si los `strings` contienen información y efectivamente traen los datos necesarios.

```
var datosparadt1 = conn.DB_Read("`Angulos`", "*", "", dataGridView18, null, "");
        dataGridView18.DataSource = datosparadt1.Item2;

        dataGridView18.Columns.Add("Cant_Egreso", "Cantidad egresada"); //6
        dataGridView18.Columns.Add("Kilos_Egreso", "Kilos Egresados"); //7

        dataGridView18.Columns.Add("Cant_ingreso", "Cantidad ingresada"); //8
        dataGridView18.Columns.Add("Kilos_ingreso", "Kilos ingresados"); //9

        dataGridView18.Columns.Add("Cant_Reserva", "Cantidad reservada"); //10
        dataGridView18.Columns.Add("Kilos_Reserva", "Kilos reservados"); //11

        for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView18.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            string _ValorBuscado = dataGridView18.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            string _tabla = "materiaprima_materiales";

            string _CantidadEgreso = conn.CalcularStocks(_tabla, _ValorBuscado, "Cant", "Egreso");             
            string _KilosEgreso = conn.CalcularStocks(_tabla, _ValorBuscado, "PesoTotal", "Egreso");

            string _CantidadIngreso = conn.CalcularStocks(_tabla, _ValorBuscado, "Cant", "Ingreso");
            string _KilosIngreso = conn.CalcularStocks(_tabla, _ValorBuscado, "PesoTotal", "Ingreso");

            string _CantidadReserva = conn.CalcularStocks(_tabla, _ValorBuscado, "Cant", "Reserva");
            string _KilosReserva = conn.CalcularStocks(_tabla, _ValorBuscado, "PesoTotal", "Reserva");


            dataGridView18.Rows[i].Cells["Cant_Egreso"].Value = _CantidadEgreso;
            dataGridView18.Rows[i].Cells["Kilos_Egreso"].Value = _KilosEgreso;

            dataGridView18.Rows[i].Cells["Cant_ingreso"].Value = _CantidadIngreso;
            dataGridView18.Rows[i].Cells["Kilos_ingreso"].Value = _KilosIngreso;

            dataGridView18.Rows[i].Cells["Cant_Reserva"].Value = _CantidadReserva;
            dataGridView18.Rows[i].Cells["Kilos_Reserva"].Value = _KilosReserva;
        }
```

En las celdas en blanco deberían figurar los datos calculados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Datos que se cargan correctamente en las variables.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Casos fallidos

Probe con un foreach para cada Row de la DataGridView.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probe con cambiar el AutoGenerateColumns a false pero este me da como error NullReferenceException

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Se recuerda

las columnas que tienen valores salen de una base de datos, mientras que las columnas que aparecen sin valores son creadas desde el codigo mediante `DataGridView.Columns.Add(*,*)` una vez que las creo paso a intentar ingresarle información pero nunca se cargan.

Fíjense que el dato SI se carga correctamente en el DataGridView pero luego se borra.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Vale , dices que tu guardas los datos en tus variables y luego intentas plasmarlos en en Row y estos estan en blanco, que no se termina de actualizar la Row con la nueva informacion?

Comment: Si, eso es lo que intente describir.

Comment: Has probado a en lugar de  `Cells["Cant_Egreso"]` poner `Cells["Cantidad egresada"]` ya que a lo mejor busca por nombre?

Comment: Si y trae un error de que no encuentra la celda, también probé con la numeración de la columna en vez del nombre pero pasa lo mismo.

Comment: Acabo de probar tu codigo en mi VisualStudio y me funciona correctamente. Obviamente las variable "_" son strings a mano, pero me las inserta correctamente. Debe de ser alguna propiedad del datagridView. Fijate en la propiedad **HeaderText** (DataGridView => Columm)  ya que ese es el valor que va a buscar cuando hagas el `Cells["Cant_Egreso"]`

Comment: No encuentro esa propiedad HeaderText, en donde la puedo ubicar?.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96566/discussion-between-capt-teach-and-martin-fernandez).

Comment: El `HeaderText ` no veo que tenga relacion, la busqueda se realiza con el `Name` de la columna

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que recomendaria valides es que tengas la propiedad `AutoGenerateColumns` en `false`

[GridView.AutoGenerateColumns Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns?view=netframework-4.5)

puede que esas columans que observas se esten generando al bindear los datos

Despues para agregar la nueva informacion itera las rows usando

```
dataGridView18.Columns.Add("CantEgreso", "Cantidad egresada");

string _tabla = "materiaprima_materiales";

foreach(var row in dataGridView18.Rows)
{
     string _ValorBuscado = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

     string _CantidadEgreso = conn.CalcularStocks(_tabla, _ValorBuscado, "Cant", "Egreso");

     row.Cells["CantEgreso"].Value = _CantidadEgreso;
}
```

Intenta definiendo un nombre de columna sin el `_`.

Ademas asigna una sola row a ver como resulta despues puede agregar el resto

Comment: row.Cells me devuelve un error.
Si paso a false el AutoGenerateColumns tambien me devuelve un error sobre que no encuentra la fila en cuestion.

Comment: Podrias mencionar exactamente que dice el mensaje de error en cada caso, porque si el codigo lo has escrito correctamente no deberia fallar. Edita la pregunta y agrega lo nuevo que has intentado, puede publicar algo del codigo y los mesajes

Comment: Has visto el edit que hice?

Comment: pero sigues usando el `for` porque no lo cambiaste al `foreach` ? recuerda que al definir el AutoGenerateColumns en false debes definir las columnas en tiempo de diseño, ya que tu controlas cuales se van a visualizar, indicando el `DataPropertyName` con el nombre de la columna del datatable

Comment: El foreach me trae un problema. fijate que subo lo que me dice si intento hacer un foreach. intente subir el valor en otra celda (de las que ya tenian informacion) y ahi si aparece el valor correctamente (sobrescribiendo el anterior claro) quiza eso te sirva de indicio

Comment: la verdad no entiendo que estas codificando, `row` no puede ser nunca un object, porque es un DataGridViewRow que es lo que iteras, es mas si defines `foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView18.Rows)` es lo mismo que usar el `var`